# iTunes search API undefined first result

Tags: json, api, itunes

Hi I'm struggling for a long time with the itunes api album listing.

My issue is the thumbnail and album title in the first `<li></li>` always comes back as undefined.

The code is based on itunes artist search which works as intended, but my version for album listing always gives this glitch.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var searchTerm = '909253';
  $.getJSON( "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=" + searchTerm + '&limit=30' + '&entity=album' + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function() {
      $('<li></li>')
        .hide()
        .append('<img src="' + this.artworkUrl60 + '" />' ) 
        .append('<span><a href="http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=' 
          + this.artistName + '">' + 'Artist: ' + this.artistName
          + '</a> ' + '<br />Album Title: '  + this.collectionName + '</span>')
        .appendTo('#results')
        .fadeIn();
    });        
    $("#results").listview("refresh");
  });
});
```

​
See http://jsfiddle.net/tris_wood/u2sYe/2/

I've seen similar posts with this issue wth the itunes api but no solutions that I could find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your code to your question? It saves us from making the jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the first returned element is always the parent element, in this case the artist.

If you request:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253&entity=album
```

You will get (as you can see in wrapperType):

```
0) Artist information
1) First album
2) Second album
```

Unfortunately your code is temporary offline at the moment and I can't check if my intuition is correct.

Comment: Ah right. I see. It actually works for artists that only have one track but i still cannot get it running properly.

Would you mind looking again as jsfiddle is back up. Many thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/tris_wood/u2sYe/2/

Comment: As you can see from the jsfiddle by printing `data.results` the first result is an artist. You can easily strip away with data.results.shift(). http://jsfiddle.net/sWVY8/